# Protobuf-net Serialize/Deserialize to/from byte arrays

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am working in a GC sensitive environment, and am interested in serializing / deserializing protobuf from preallocated byte arrays instead of memory streams. Is this possible with the protobuf-net library?

Comment: How would you know how big to make your buffers for serialization?

Answer (score 5):

You can initialise a `MemoryStream` with a pre-allocated buffer, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) overload. You could probably go so far as to allocate one large buffer and index into bits of it using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63z365ty.aspx) overload.

You can then pass this stream to protobuf as usual.