# How do I deserialize a binary AMQP message received with protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net, godot, amqpnetlite

I am just learning C# and am using it with Godot. We are trying to send a binary Protobuf-encoded message from a client over AMQP and receive it with the C# script running in Godot.

I am at the point where the message is received and I am trying to deserialize it. The message body is a 44-byte array, but the protobuf-net deserialize doesn't take a byte array. The message body is of type `object` but it definitely contains a byte array.

```cs
    byte[] binaryBody = (byte[])message.Body;
    CommandBuffer commandBuffer;
    commandBuffer = Serializer.Deserialize<CommandBuffer>(binaryBody);
```

This results in an error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Serializer.Deserialize<T>(ReadOnlyMemory<byte>, T, object)' and 'Serializer.Deserialize<T>(ReadOnlySpan<byte>, T, object)' [srt-godot-test]csharp(CS0121)
```

Trying to convert `binaryBody` to a `MemoryStream` results in all kind of a mess and a protobuf that cannot be properly decoded:

```csharp
    MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream();
    st.Write(binaryBody, 0, binaryBody.Length);
```

It seems like I should just be able to deserialize `binaryBody` somehow, but I cannot figure out what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post:
[Protobuf-net Serialize/Deserialize to/from byte arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24329961/protobuf-net-serialize-deserialize-to-from-byte-arrays)

Which lead me to the `MemoryStream` page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_IO_MemoryStream__ctor_System_Byte___

And I noticed this option:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-memorystream-ctor(system-byte()-system-boolean)

Which resulted in this code:

```csharp
  void GameEventReceived(IReceiverLink receiver, Message message)
  {
    GD.Print("Event received!");
    // accept the message so that it gets removed from the queue
    receiver.Accept(message);

    byte[] binaryBody = (byte[])message.Body;

    MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream(binaryBody, false);

    // prep a command buffer for processing the message
    CommandBuffer commandBuffer;
    commandBuffer = Serializer.Deserialize<CommandBuffer>(st);
  }
```

The key was creating the `MemoryStream` *directly* from the bytestring.